# How to insert to latitude and longitude in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I am developing a mvc5 web application. I am trying to store the user's location (Latitude, Longitude) to a database. I can save the location name. But, i can't save latitude and longitude info. How can i insert these?

Thanks for your help.

**listing.Cshtml file:**

```
   <fieldset>
                            <legend>[[[Location]]]</legend>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>[[[Location]]]</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="[[[Enter Location]]]" id="Location" name="Location" value="@Model.ListingItem.Location">
                            </div>

                            <input type="hidden" id="Longitude" name="Longitude" value="@Model.ListingItem.Longitude" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="Latitude" name="Latitude" value="@Model.ListingItem.Latitude" />

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                            </div>

 </fieldset>
```

**listingController:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ListingUpdate(Listing listing, FormCollection form, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (CacheHelper.Categories.Count == 0)
        {
            TempData[TempDataKeys.UserMessageAlertState] = "bg-danger";
            TempData[TempDataKeys.UserMessage] = "[[[There are not categories available yet.]]]";

            return RedirectToAction("Listing", new { id = listing.ID });
        }

        var userIdCurrent = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        // Register account if not login
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var accountController = BeYourMarket.Core.ContainerManager.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<AccountController>();

            var modelRegister = new RegisterViewModel()
            {
                Email = listing.ContactEmail,
                Password = form["Password"],
                ConfirmPassword = form["ConfirmPassword"],
            };

            // Parse first and last name
            var names = listing.ContactName.Split(' ');
            if (names.Length == 1)
            {
                modelRegister.FirstName = names[0];
            }
            else if (names.Length == 2)
            {
                modelRegister.FirstName = names[0];
                modelRegister.LastName = names[1];
            }
            else if (names.Length > 2)
            {
                modelRegister.FirstName = names[0];
                modelRegister.LastName = listing.ContactName.Substring(listing.ContactName.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
            }

            // Register account
            var resultRegister = await accountController.RegisterAccount(modelRegister);

            // Add errors
            AddErrors(resultRegister);

            // Show errors if not succeed
            if (!resultRegister.Succeeded)
            {
                var model = new ListingUpdateModel()
                {
                    ListingItem = listing
                };
                // Populate model with listing
                await PopulateListingUpdateModel(listing, model);
                return View("ListingUpdate", model);
            }

            // update current user id
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(listing.ContactEmail);
            userIdCurrent = user.Id;
        }

        bool updateCount = false;

        int nextPictureOrderId = 0;

        // Set default listing type ID
        if (listing.ListingTypeID == 0)
        {
            var listingTypes = CacheHelper.ListingTypes.Where(x => x.CategoryListingTypes.Any(y => y.CategoryID == listing.CategoryID));

            if (listingTypes == null)
            {
                TempData[TempDataKeys.UserMessageAlertState] = "bg-danger";
                TempData[TempDataKeys.UserMessage] = "[[[There are not listing types available yet.]]]";

                return RedirectToAction("Listing", new { id = listing.ID });
            }

            listing.ListingTypeID = listingTypes.FirstOrDefault().ID;
        }

        if (listing.ID == 0)
        {
            listing.ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Added;
            listing.IP = Request.GetVisitorIP();
            listing.Expiration = DateTime.MaxValue.AddDays(-1);
            listing.UserID = userIdCurrent;
            listing.Enabled = true;
            listing.Currency = CacheHelper.Settings.Currency;

            updateCount = true;
            _listingService.Insert(listing);
        }
        else
        {
            if (await NotMeListing(listing.ID))
                return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

            var listingExisting = await _listingService.FindAsync(listing.ID);

            listingExisting.Title = listing.Title;
            listingExisting.Description = listing.Description;
            listingExisting.Tags = listing.Tags;
            listingExisting.Active = listing.Active;
            listingExisting.Price = listing.Price;

            listingExisting.ContactEmail = listing.ContactEmail;
            listingExisting.ContactName = listing.ContactName;
            listingExisting.ContactPhone = listing.ContactPhone;

            listingExisting.Latitude = listing.Latitude;
            listingExisting.Longitude = listing.Longitude;
            listingExisting.Location = listing.Location;

            listingExisting.ShowPhone = listing.ShowPhone;
            listingExisting.ShowEmail = listing.ShowEmail;

            listingExisting.CategoryID = listing.CategoryID;
            listingExisting.ListingTypeID = listing.ListingTypeID;

            listingExisting.ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Modified;

            _listingService.Update(listingExisting);
        }

        // Delete existing fields on item
        var customFieldItemQuery = await _customFieldListingService.Query(x => x.ListingID == listing.ID).SelectAsync();
        var customFieldIds = customFieldItemQuery.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
        foreach (var customFieldId in customFieldIds)
        {
            await _customFieldListingService.DeleteAsync(customFieldId);
        }

        // Get custom fields
        var customFieldCategoryQuery = await _customFieldCategoryService.Query(x => x.CategoryID == listing.CategoryID).Include(x => x.MetaField.ListingMetas).SelectAsync();
        var customFieldCategories = customFieldCategoryQuery.ToList();

        foreach (var metaCategory in customFieldCategories)
        {
            var field = metaCategory.MetaField;
            var controlType = (BeYourMarket.Model.Enum.Enum_MetaFieldControlType)field.ControlTypeID;

            string controlId = string.Format("customfield_{0}_{1}_{2}", metaCategory.ID, metaCategory.CategoryID, metaCategory.FieldID);

            var formValue = form[controlId];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formValue))
                continue;

            formValue = formValue.ToString();

            var itemMeta = new ListingMeta()
            {
                ListingID = listing.ID,
                Value = formValue,
                FieldID = field.ID,
                ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Added
            };

            _customFieldListingService.Insert(itemMeta);
        }

        await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var itemPictureQuery = _listingPictureservice.Queryable().Where(x => x.ListingID == listing.ID);
            if (itemPictureQuery.Count() > 0)
                nextPictureOrderId = itemPictureQuery.Max(x => x.Ordering);
        }

        if (files != null && files.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
                {
                    // Picture picture and get id
                    var picture = new Picture();
                    picture.MimeType = "image/jpeg";
                    _pictureService.Insert(picture);
                    await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();

                    // Format is automatically detected though can be changed.
                    ISupportedImageFormat format = new JpegFormat { Quality = 90 };
                    Size size = new Size(500, 0);

                    //https://naimhamadi.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/processing-images-in-c-easily-using-imageprocessor/
                    // Initialize the ImageFactory using the overload to preserve EXIF metadata.
                    using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true))
                    {
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/listing"), string.Format("{0}.{1}", picture.ID.ToString("00000000"), "jpg"));

                        // Load, resize, set the format and quality and save an image.
                        imageFactory.Load(file.InputStream)
                                    .Resize(size)
                                    .Format(format)
                                    .Save(path);
                    }

                    var itemPicture = new ListingPicture();
                    itemPicture.ListingID = listing.ID;
                    itemPicture.PictureID = picture.ID;
                    itemPicture.Ordering = nextPictureOrderId;

                    _listingPictureservice.Insert(itemPicture);

                    nextPictureOrderId++;
                }
            }
        }

        await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Update statistics count
        if (updateCount)
        {
            _sqlDbService.UpdateCategoryItemCount(listing.CategoryID);
            _dataCacheService.RemoveCachedItem(CacheKeys.Statistics);
        }

        TempData[TempDataKeys.UserMessage] = "[[[Listing is updated!]]]";
        return RedirectToAction("Listing", new { id = listing.ID });
    }
```

My page screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGWqg.png)

Consequently, i can insert location in my db. But, i can't latitude and longitude insert.

How can i solve this problem?

**initmap function:**

```
function initMap() {
        var isDraggable = $(document).width() > 480 ? true : false; // If document (your website) is wider than 480px, isDraggable = true, else isDraggable = false

        var mapOptions = {
            draggable: isDraggable,
            scrollwheel: false, // Prevent users to start zooming the map when scrolling down the page
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.8688, 32.2195),
        };

        @{ var hasLatLng = @Model.ListingItem.Latitude.HasValue && @Model.ListingItem.Longitude.HasValue; }
        var hasLatLng = @hasLatLng.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();

        @if (hasLatLng){
            <text>
        mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.ListingItem.Latitude.Value.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), @Model.ListingItem.Longitude.Value.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
            zoom: 7
        };
        </text>
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);

        @if (hasLatLng){
            <text>
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.ListingItem.Latitude, @Model.ListingItem.Longitude),
            map: map
        });

        marker.setVisible(true);
        </text>
        }

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var input = (document.getElementById('Location'));
        // Try HTML5 geolocation
        if (@Model.ListingItem.ID == 0){
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                                     position.coords.longitude);


                    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': pos }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results[1]) {
                                map.setZoom(14);
                                map.setCenter(pos);

                                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: pos,
                                    map: map,
                                    content: results[1].formatted_address
                                });
                                infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);

                                $('#Location').val(results[1].formatted_address);
                                $('#Latitude').val(pos.lat());
                                $('#Longitude').val(pos.lng());                                    

                            } else {
                                alert('No results found');
                            }
                        } else {
                            alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                        }
                    });
                }, function () {
                    handleNoGeolocation(true);
                });
            } else {
                // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                handleNoGeolocation(false);
            }
        }

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
                return;
            }

            // Set lat/long
            $('#Latitude').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
            $('#Longitude').val(place.geometry.location.lng());

            // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(12);
            }
            marker.setIcon(({
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
            }));
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);

            var address = '';
            if (place.address_components) {
                address = [
                  (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                  (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                  (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                ].join(' ');
            }

            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(input, 'keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    // Since the google event handler framework does not handle
                    e.cancelBubble = true;
                    e.returnValue = false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

**save button:**

```
  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> [[[Save]]]</button>
         <a href="@Url.Action("Listings", "Listing")" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> [[[Cancel]]]</a>
       </div>
   </div>
```